# handshake_failure when try to TLS handshake Client Authentication with SmartCard

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2, handshake

Request Client Certificate enabled in Apache server and SSL configured. All works with browser such as Chrome. But  we are trying to create client app for authentication with SmartCard certificate PKCS11 directly (without browser).

Here is the main code:

```
        String configName = "d:/config.txt";

        SunPKCS11 sunpkcs11 = new SunPKCS11(configName);
        Security.addProvider(sunpkcs11);
        KeyStore keyStore = null;

        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11",sunpkcs11);
        keyStore.load(null, pin.toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(keyStore, pin.toCharArray());


        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
        SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);
        final SSLSocketFactory factory = ctx.getSocketFactory();
        final SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("xx.xx.xx.xx", 443);

        socket.startHandshake();   

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

        String fileName = "/Login";
        out.print("GET " + fileName + " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
        out.print("\r\n");
        out.flush();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
          System.out.println(line);
```

Error occurs when handshake step runs.

Stack trace exception:

```
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failu
```

In Apache logs  we get this:

```
Certificate Verification: Error (20): unable to get local issuer certificate
```

And Java App occurs this error:

```
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that SSLContext is unable to properly use the PKCS # 11 provider to access the smartcard, and then the server shutdown the connection because the client has not sent the signature.

¿Could you attach the entire handshake log to see each step in detail?

```
 -Djavax.net.debug=ssl
```

Chrome uses Windows KeyStore, so it not the same case. Because your java code is using the SunPKCS11 provider.

Have you tried to use smartcard through the Windows KeyStore?

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
keystore.load(null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks @pedrofb, I've used `Windows-MY` it pops up and asks PIN2. But this error occurs `Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Error signing certificate verify`

Comment: I guess if a window is popped up and it was not you, was the driver. Therefore you will not be able to put the PIN2 by code (check the smartcard technical specification). Smartcards manufacturers do so to prevent PIN2 falling into the wrong hands

Comment: Thanks @pedrofb, what about exception? `Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Error signing certificate verify`

Comment: It could be a compatibility problem between JDK security classes and keystore. Can you post the entier handshake log using PCKS#11 and Windows-MY? Which java version are you using?

Comment: We are using java 8

Comment: With PKCS@11 provider, the connection is closed inmediately. I can not see anything to resolve. With Windows-MY the problem occurs when the Handshake  process requests smartcard to sign the challenge at sun.security.mscapi.RSASignature.signHash(Native Method). It is using the mscapi cryptographic provider. It is possible that this provider do not support the signature algorithm requested by protocol. I will search if it is possible to use other cryptographic provider than sun.mscapi. In other way, have you installed in your JRE the unlimited security policy?

Comment: Thank you @pedrofb, We are actually using JRE unlimited security policy. If you will have any other information please let me know. THanks